# C# Split not working

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm trying to read data from a file, split the data and save to array. The code works fine except for the split. It is returning a `NullException`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public static void LoadHandData(CurrentHand[] handData, string fileName)
    {
        string input = ""; //temporary variable to hold one line of data
        string[] cardData; //temporary array to hold data split from input

        StreamReader readHand = new StreamReader(fileName);

        for (int counter = 0; counter < handData.Length; counter++)
        {

            input = readHand.ReadLine(); //one record
            cardData = input.Split(' '); //split record into fields

            int index = 0;
            handData[counter].cardSuit = Convert.ToChar(cardData[index++]);
            handData[counter].cardValue = Convert.ToInt16(cardData[index++]);
        }
        readHand.Close();
    }
```

Comment: *Where* are you getting the exception? I suspect you'll find that basically you don't have enough lines in your file. How large is `handData` and how long is your file? `ReadLine()` returns `null` if it's reached the end of the data.

Comment: You should maybe consider a guard claus after the Readline just to make sure it's not null before splitting.

Comment: the file is just one line ie. C 12 S 12 C 7 H 5 D 2. I'm trying to split the char's and the int into (hand Data) array of structs

Comment: input is not null. input is holding the file data.

Comment: If your file is just one line then won't a second iteration of the loop return `null` on `readHand.ReadLine()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the comments, you've only got one line of data. But look at your loop:

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < handData.Length; counter++)
{
    input = readHand.ReadLine(); //one record
    cardData = input.Split(' '); //split record into fields

    int index = 0;
    handData[counter].cardSuit = Convert.ToChar(cardData[index++]);
    handData[counter].cardValue = Convert.ToInt16(cardData[index++]);
}
```

That's trying to read one line *per hand*. On the second iteration, `ReadLine` will return `null`, so when you call `input.Split()` you'll end up with the `NullReferenceException` you're seeing.

You need to read the line *once* and split it. Given that you've only got one line of text, you can just use `File.ReadAllText` to simplify things:

```
string input = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
string[] cardData = input.Split(' ');

for (int counter = 0; counter < handData.Length; counter++)
{
    handData[counter].cardSuit = Convert.ToChar(cardData[counter * 2]);
    handData[counter].cardValue = Convert.ToInt16(cardData[counter * 2 + 1]);
}
```